# aligning HTML table for use in outlook email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-table

attempting to build a email template for outlook (does not need to work on any other email clients) using the incredibly frustrating 90's style table layout technique.

my HTML is below, what I want is for the "supporting content" section to vertically align with the "new launches" section. I cant think of any way to do this other than using the vertical align css property, however outlook doesnt support this.

Any ideas anyone?

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">

<tr>

<td width="80%">
    main content
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="100%">
            New launches
            </td>
                    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width = "50%">
            launch 1. launch one information blah blah blah
            </td>
            <td width = "50%">
            launch 1 images, lots of images here, blah blah
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width = "50%">
            launch 2. launch one information blah blah blah
            </td>
            <td width = "50%">
            launch 2 images, lots of images here, blah blah
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width = "50%">
            launch 3. launch one information blah blah blah
            </td>
            <td width = "50%">
            launch 3 images, lots of images here, blah blah
            </td>
        </tr>
<td width="100%">
            completed tests
            </td>
                    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width = "50%">
            completed 1. launch one information blah blah blah
            </td>
            <td width = "50%">
            completed 1 images, lots of images here, blah blah
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width = "50%">
            completed 2. launch one information blah blah blah
            </td>
            <td width = "50%">
            completed 2 images, lots of images here, blah blah
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width = "50%">
            completed 3. launch one information blah blah blah
            </td>
            <td width = "50%">
            completed 3 images, lots of images here, blah blah
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    </td>

<td width="20%" vertical-align = "top">
    supporting content
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td width = "100%">
            supporting content section 1
            </td>
        <td width = "100%">
            supporting content section 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        </tr>

    </td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I havent added any yet, just want to get the layout working first before i make it look good

Comment: @Siyah Sorry I mean the only css im using so far in inline in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `style` attribute like:

```
<td style="width:20%; vertical-align:top" >
```

Comment: sorry, as i mentioned, i tried vertical align and its unsupported in outlook

Comment: ah apologies dumisani, you are absolutely right. Slight banging my head against the wall mistake here. Perfect, thank you very much

Comment: Alright, I pasted your code on fiddle and it did not align to top, but after I used the `style` attribute it worked. was guessing outlook could behave the same

Comment: yeah you are totally right, it was my mistake! think i need more coffee!

Comment: Lol don't add too much sugar. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no such html property as "vertical-align", it's css one. Try

```
<td width="20%" valign="top">
```

That one worked for me (as far as Litmus shows), both for desktop application and webmail

Answer (score 1):

Few bugs found in your HTML

```
<td width="100%">
    completed tests
</td>
```

does not have a starting `<tr>` tag

---

```
<td width="20%" vertical-align="top">
    supporting content
```

does not have a matching closing `</td>` [It have a `</tr>` before the matching `</td>`]

After making above corrections, change

```
<td width="80%">
    main content
```

to

```
<td width="80%" valign="top"> <!-- note the added valign="top" -->
    main content
```

and

```
<td width="20%">
    supporting content
```

to

```
<td width="20%" valign="top">
    supporting content
```